# Knockout JS setting optionsValue destroys my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The code below is simplified, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QTUqD/7/

Basically I'm setting the device name under the data-bind, but I also need to specify the optionsValue for sending off to the database, but when I set it, the display data-bind is blank.

```
<script id="extItems" type="text/html">
   <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: device() && device().name"></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="editExts" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>

        <select data-bind="options: $root.devicesForItem($data), optionsText: 'name', value: device, optionsValue: 'id'"></select>

        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

---

```
    window.ExtListViewModel = new function () {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.list = ko.observableArray();

    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.extQty = ko.observable();
    self.devices = ko.observableArray();
    self.addressList = ko.observableArray(['addressList']);
    self.availableDevices = ko.computed(function() {        
        var usedQuantities = {}; // for each device id, store the used quantity
        self.list().forEach(function(item) {
            var device = item.device();
            if (device) {
                usedQuantities[device.id] = 1 + (usedQuantities[device.id] || 0);
            }
        });

        return self.devices().filter(function(device) {
            var usedQuantity = usedQuantities[device.id] || 0;
            return device.qty > usedQuantity;
        });
    });

    // need this to add back item's selected device to its device-options,
    // and to maintain original order of devices
    self.devicesForItem = function(item) {        
        var availableDevices = self.availableDevices();
        return self.devices().filter(function(device) {
            return device === item.device() || availableDevices.indexOf(device) !== -1;
        });
    }

    self.edit = function (item) {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
        }
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.add = function () {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            var newItem = new Extension();
            self.list.push(newItem);
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
            self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
        }
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {

            if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {

                    self.list.remove(item);
                    if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                        self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
                    }

            }
            $('.error').hide();
    };
    self.save = function () {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            self.selectedItem(null);
        };
    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editExts' : 'extItems';
    };

    self.pagedList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        return self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    });
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.list().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
    });
    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
            pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };


};

ko.applyBindings(ExtListViewModel, document.getElementById('extMngForm'));

function Extension(extension, name, email, vmpin, device, macAddress, shipTo){
    this.extension = ko.observable(extension);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
    this.vmpin = ko.observable(vmpin);
    this.device = ko.observable(device);
    this.macAddress = ko.observable(macAddress);
    this.shipTo = ko.observable(shipTo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `optionsValue`, KO writes the property value to whatever you have bound against `value`.  So, it would now populate value with the id rather than the object.

There are a couple of ways to tackle this scenario where you want both the value (for sending to the DB) and the object (for binding other parts of the UI against).

A pretty typical solution is to create a computed observable on your object that takes the currently selected object and returns the id.

So, in your `Extension` you would do something like:

```
this.device = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var device = this.device.asObject();
        return device && device.id;
    },
    deferEvaluation: true, //deferring evaluation, as device.asObject has not been created yet
}, this);

//create this as a sub-observable, so it just disappears when we turn this into JSON and we are just left with the id to send to the DB
this.device.asObject = ko.observable(device);
```

Then remove the `optionsValue` and bind `value` against `device.asObject`

In this case, I added the `asObject` sub-observable, so it will just drop off when you turn this into JSON (`ko.toJSON`) to send to the server. The only tricky part about this technique is that if you are loading existing data from the server, then you would need to populate `asObject` with the appropriate choice from your options.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Q3PEv/

Another option that I have used is to continue to use `optionsValue`, but then to create a custom binding that tracks the object in a separate observable.  Here is a custom binding that creates an `asObject` sub-observable for whatever is bound against `value`. This way you really don't need to mess with it at all in your view model.

```
//when using optionsValue, still track the select object in a different observable
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAsObject = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = allBindingsAccessor().value,
            prop = valueAccessor() || 'asObject';

        //add an "asObject" sub-observable to the observable bound against "value"
        if (ko.isObservable(value) && !value[prop]) {
              value[prop] = ko.observable();
        }
    },
    //whenever the value or options are updated, populated the "asObject" observable
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var prop = valueAccessor(),
            all = allBindingsAccessor(),
            options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(all.options),
            value = all.value,
            key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value),
            keyProp = all.optionsValue,
            //loop through the options, find a match based on the current "value"
            match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(options, function(option) {
               return option[keyProp] === key;
            });

        //set the "asObject" observable to our match
        value[prop](match);
    }
};
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/E2kvM/

Comment: I just noticed that you script breaks my availableDevices function. It should remove the option once the qty has exceeded the number used in the foreach. Any ideas?